# How to retrieve the list of games from xbox API?

Tags: php, api, xbox360, xbox

i am trying to retrieve a list of all xbox one games that are on xbox marketplace.

The example from documentation:

> https://xboxapi.com/v2/browse-marketplace/games/1?sort=releaseDate

This query returns only 20 records at time. So the problem is, you need to pass the page number.
I can make a loop but it will obviously make more calls, which will have a big impact on the performance.
Is there a way to retrieve all games at once, or at least in bigger chunks?

thx

Comment: according to the documentation: no. The response will give you a `X-Continuation-Token` header for the next request.

Comment: yeah, seems like the only solution is to make a pagination. Or to fetch the data with a task.

Answer (score 0):

For this endpoint, you can see there is a 1 at the end of the URI. This is one of the few endpoints that Microsoft don't offer continuation tokens on, and instead increment a page number. So to get the next page, it would be;

> https://xboxapi.com/v2/browse-marketplace/games/2?sort=releaseDate

and

> https://xboxapi.com/v2/browse-marketplace/games/3?sort=releaseDate

so on, and so on.

~djekl

Comment: That's what i said in the first comment. But immagine i need to fetch 20 pages. I will have to do 20 requests. How it will impact the performance?

Comment: @AdrianC. you down voted me as the owner and developer of XboxAPI, I provided the ONLY way that you can get the results using my API. The limited number of results per page is a limitation from Microsoft, not XboxAPI.

Comment: this is not what i asked, and you said what i already i knew,  and said in the first post.

Comment: If your trying to populate all the xbox games available, id recommend scanning the xbox one and xbox 360 games of some of the highest earned gamerscore users.

You can easily get 500-600 xbox one games scanning stallion in 1 call.

But Djekl is right, Microsoft limit it to 20, so you would have to request each page.

Comment: It says no api key provided, can you please share the link to documentation? Thanks!